# What is compensated compactness?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, compactness, weak-convergence

As the title says, what is compensated compactness? I see people talk about it in the books and papers I am reading but I can only find hand wavy definitions when I look online. Is there a definition or is it just a general idea that covers theorems to give some nice convergence results given some sort of compactness?

Thanks!

Comment: The general idea is that if you have two sequences $f_n$ and $g_n$ in $L^2$, and if those sequences have special properties, then their product $f_n g_n$ are in an $H^1$ space rather than $L^1$.  And much weaker hypotheses can be used to show that $f_n g_n$ have a convergent subsequence if you know it is in $H^1$.  But you probably knew this already.

Comment: I agree. This seems to be the general idea. I don't know if there is a general definition. Maybe it is like a "stiff equation" - i hear it is just a general concept and people just know whether an equation is considered stiff or not depending on the example!!

Comment: I am looking at http://www.math.missouri.edu/~loukas/preprints/rochberg.pdf - Theorem 2.  The problem is to find an analogue of weak convergence for $L^1$.  The nice thing about $H^1$ is that you can use the space VMO to define a kind of convergence.  (In spaces like $L^p$ for $1<p<\infty$, they are reflexive, and so the unit ball is weakly compact).  What other kinds of convergence results have you seen in the literature?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_mean_oscillation#The_space_VMO This says that VMO is a predual of $H^1$.  Thus the unit ball of $H^1$ is weak* compact.  I think that's the main thing - $L^1$ doesn't generally have a predual.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith Apologies for my limited knowledge of functional analysis but what does weak* compactness give us?
Also, in response to your question, the convergence result I am looking at is the div-curl lemma.

Comment: The unit ball of a Banach space is weak* compact.  Hence for any sequence you can find a cluster point.  And under some circumstances, you can show the unit ball is sequentially compact, but I don't remember precisely when.  So you can always find a subsequence that converges in the weak* topology.

Comment: Ok I think I understand. Is $H^1$ the most natural space? I haven't seen many other spaces mentioned in the literature e.g. under certain circumstances the determinant of the Jacobian maps into $H^1$ (see Compensated Compactness and Hardy Spaces by R. Coifman et al.)

Comment: Yes, $H^1$ is the most natural space.  There are a lot of results that hold for $L^p$ for $1<p<\infty$, but don't hold for $L^1$ or $L^\infty$.  The canonical example is the boundedness of the Hilbert transform.  But then they found $H^1$ and BMO as replacement spaces.

Comment: Thanks. I always wondered the uses of these spaces as they are not really talked about much in many undergraduate courses.